# Set the content-type for one file in jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I use the example [Basic Plus UI](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)
from the jQuery File Upload plugin as a basis for my own page, and everything works
well.  I am able to pass additional form fields for each individual file upload as
[explained here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data),
using the `*submit` event.

I would like to extend it to actually set the Content-Type used by the plugin when
it sends the file to the server (the Content-Type "pseudo-header" of the corresponding
part in the HTTP multipart request.)

But I have not seen any documentation about how to set a file Content-Type on the
wiki, and I could not find how it is set in the code.

The current code of the event handler, just in case:

```
// event handler to set the additional input fields
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (evt, data) {

   // the input elements
   var inputs = data.context.find(':input');

   // missing any required value?
   if ( missingRequired(inputs) ) {
      data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      return false;
   }

   // set the form data from the input elements
   data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();

   // set the content type based on format

   // *****
   // How can I set the "current" file content-type to, say, "text/plain" ?
   // *****
}
```